# Using each with not

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to take action on all divs with an ID that isn't "first". But somehow, when I run my each loop, it ignores the first div and goes on to the next one. I have a sense that this is an easy fix...

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each($(".storyBlock:not(:first)"), function(i, object){
        console.log(i); //returns 0 for the second item, 1 for the third item
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="storyBlock" id="second" style="margin-top:1500px" img="mypathhere"></div>
    <div class="storyBlock" id="third" style="margin-top:1500px" img="mypathhere"></div>
    <div class="storyBlock" id="fourth" style="margin-top:1500px" img="mypathhere"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @karthikr: except that your fiddle doesn't take an action on an item whose id is not "first". See the answers for what I think the OP wants.

Comment: I recommend to use `$(...).each(...)`. I'd argue that's the more "natural" way to iterate over selections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, you're targetting the first item with class storyBlock (that's what the `:first` does), so it's not a bug but a feature.

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.each($(".storyBlock:not(#first)"), function(i, object){

        console.log(i);//returns 0 for the second item, 1 for the third item

    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`:first` is different from `#first`.  The former is the first element in a group of elements, and `#first` is an element with the ID attribute of `first`, which seems to be what you want.

Note that you can also write this as:

```
$(".storyBlock:not(#first)").each
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.not()` traversing API for this as well...

http://api.jquery.com/not/

```
(".storyBlock").not("#first").each(function(i, object){
    console.log(i);//returns 0 for the second item, 1 for the third item
});
```

[`First`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) is a selector that will literally give you the first element of a matched element.

Answer (score 1):

an ID of first has a `#first` selector

So `$(".storyBlock:not(#first)")` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
$('.storyBlock:not(:first)').each(function() {})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.each($(".storyBlock:not([id='first'])"), function(i, object){

        console.log(i);//returns 0 for the second item, 1 for the third item

    });
});
```

Comment: You can just use `#first` instead of the attribute selector there, by the way.